# Error in class declaration, "testbuild" unable to resolve to a type

Tags: android, android-testing, android-instrumentation

I was trying to test activity lifecycle of an application(testbuild). As i start writing testcase class, i am getting errors in the class declaration that "testbuild" cannot be resolved to a type. Please someone fix this.

```
package com.example.testbuild.test;
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import com.example.testbuild.*;
public class second extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<testbuild> 
{
}
```

Comment: What is `testbuild`? Is it activity? And do use `gradle` or `ant`?

Comment: testbuild is project to test.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `testbuild` you must use testable activity:

```
public class second extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<YourActivity> 
{
     //...
}
```

Comment: Error resloved, But by syntax isn't that project name/activity name?

Comment: @user2750644 sorry, I can't understand your question.

Comment: BY syntax ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<Mainproject> or ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<Youractivity>  ??

Comment: Is it possible to add activity in testing project?

Comment: @user2750644 no it's not possible. It's senseless by definition.

Comment: while testing an application, does main application open in emulator?

Comment: @user2750644 this is not a chat. One question - one answer. Read a user guide: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide It has lots of answers.